# tomcat7 local server failed to start when running java code in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat7

I was trying to run a code that posts on a user Facebook account but it fails and this error is shown :"Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost failed to start." and this is the code:

```
package com.example.tutorial;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.apache.catalina.connector.Request;

import facebook4j.*;
import facebook4j.auth.AccessToken;
/**
 * Servlet implementation class ServletExample
 */
@WebServlet("/servletexample")
public class ServletExample extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public ServletExample() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        Facebook f=new FacebookFactory().getInstance();
        String AppID="{APP_ID}",AppSecret="{APP_SECRET}";
        f.setOAuthAppId(AppID, AppSecret);
       // HttpSession session=
       // f.setOAuthPermissions(arg0);
        AccessToken accessToken=new   AccessToken("{ACCESS_TOKEN}");
        f.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);

        try {
            f.postStatusMessage("Hello World");
        } catch (FacebookException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the console :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsSRz.png)

Comment: Looks like this has nothing to do with your code (or Facebook), but with your IDE configuration.

Comment: what's that? and how do i solve that problem??

Comment: Ecplise is your IDE. How to configure that properly to test via a local Tomcat server, you’ll have to go research.